# Problem with selection from LoV oracle apex

Tags: oracle, apex, lov

I created a LoV for the a page item with following PL/SQL Code:

```
SELECT r.REASON AS displayed, r.CODE 
FROM REFUSAL_REASONS r
WHERE CODE='R';
```

I have set the following properties in the column mapping:
Return Value:SHORTCODE,
Display: DIISPLAYED,
Default Sort: DISPLAYED

The problem is all reasons are displayed. However, no matter what I select, the same reason is always selected.

Comment: I'm not following the question.  Your query has a predicate `where code = 'R'` so every row it returns will, by definition, have an `r.code` value of `R`.  If `code` is not a key, did you perhaps mean to have a return value that is the table's key?

Comment: Thank you! You are right, as Return Value I had to enter of course the ID  of the table.